# How to get width of the container in which my view is added in Android

Tags: android, view

I have a `ImageView` object inside a `LinearLayout`. I'm setting an animation to the `ImageView` which will move image view from point x to y. Now, starting point should be right corner of parent container. My question is , how do i get the dimension of the container in which the view is present. I don't see `view.getParent().getWidth()` kind of method in view hierachy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to because you can use % for animation like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="150" />
```

Comment: hmmm... i almost forgot about this option. I think this would help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
View parent = (View)view.getParent();
int width = parent.getWidth();
```

Comment: calling the getWidth to early, not drawn yet. you have to add ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener to listen when it's being drawn

Answer (score 4):

Call after view added in a parent view, otherwise you would this exeption 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getHeight()'

```
    int height = ((View) view.getParent()).getHeight();
    int width = ((View) view.getParent()).getWidth();

    int mHeight = ((View) view.getParent()).getMeasuredHeight();
    int mWidth = ((View) view.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth();
```